# Swapping variables and printing them out in C

Tags: c, variables, swap

I've written the code to accept a user y/n input, however upon running the code, the console just print out random and inconsistent characters.

```
    int main()
{
    char var1 = "A";
    char var2 = "$";
    char user_answer;

    printf("Do you wanna swap var1 and var2? y/n \n ");
    scanf("%c", &user_answer);

    if (user_answer == 'y')
    {
        var1 = "$";
        var2 = "A";
        printf("var1 is now: %c", &var1, "\n", "var2 is now: %c", &var2);
    }
    else
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have been debugging this for hours. Any corrections of what went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: A character constant is written using single quote `'a'` and not `"a"`. You printf is also wrong. You are pssing addresses instead of characters.

Comment: `char var1 = "A";`...listen to compiler warnings.

Comment: This is not the best approach to swap two variables. Search for how you can swap two variables.

Comment: @StoryTeller, thanks! That fixed the problem for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char var1 = 'A';
    char var2 = '$';
    char user_answer;

    printf("Do you wanna swap var1 and var2? y/n \n ");
    scanf("%c", &user_answer);

    if (user_answer == 'y')
    {
        var1 = '$';
        var2 = 'A';
        printf("var1 is now: %c\n",var1);
        printf("var2 is now: %c\n",var2);

    }
    else
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all `char` is not a *string* type, it's an integer<sup>1</sup> type with size 1 byte that is useful to store a single character, so yuo need to change

```
char var1 = "A";
```

to<sup>2</sup>,

```
const char *var1 = "A";
```

the same with `var2`, and then you are using `printf()` wrong, try

```
printf("var1 is now: %s\nvar2 is now: %s\n", var1, var2);
```

And [READ THE DOCUMENTATION](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>It's signed in principle.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>Use `const` because it points to a string literal which is by definition, read only.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The essential problem with your code is that you're implicitly converting a pointer to an integer with the following code:

```
char var1 = "A";
char var2 = "$";
...
```

To initialize a character you should use single quotes instead of double ones. The C compiler does not give you an error unfortunately because it actually interprets "A" as a pointer to a character which he converts to an int and since characters in C are integers no error is really produced.

By the way, you should have received a warning of the form (compiled with gcc 5.3.0):

```
jdoodle.c:2:17: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     char var1 = "A";
```

If you want to read just a single char, you probably want to use the [`getchar`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/stdio.h/getchar) function, instead of `scanf`.